# Psexec- file not on the path

Tags: psexec

```
PsExec.exe -a 0 -c -abovenormal "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.exe"
```

When I type this command in command prompt, it gives me an error that says:

> The Specified File is not on the path.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the user does not have permission to access the file. You can specify a different user with the `-u username` and `-p password` options.

You are running the command locally, but I also encountered this error when the remote (target) computer name was incorrect.

According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), lowest numbered CPU should be 1, not 0. Also, the `-c` flag doesn't make sense in this context, because you are targeting the local machine. You probably don't want to copy a file from the local machine to the local machine.

`PsExec.exe -a 1 -abovenormal -u sally.user -p mypassword "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.exe"`

Comment: Sorry to be OT.. Wanted to say I loved your answer about exercise tips in the question about the overweight teen.

Comment: Thanks, @SurestTexas :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps related, perhaps not, but I was getting a similar error "The specified application is not on the path".  Strangely, fully qualifying the psexec command made that error go away for me. Even though psexec is on the PATH of the source machine you are running on and is found when running without fully qualifying, it still gives an error "The specified application is not on the path".